# How to change the time of day Backups creates a backup in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, backup, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to use the built-in application `Backups` in Ubuntu 16.04 to backup my system. However, it seems I can only choose to schedule a backup every day at some unlisted time. The application keeps popping up at around 4:30 PM, but that's not a good time for me to make a backup. How can I change the time of day it creates a backup to be something more reasonable, like 6:00 AM every day?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

'Backups' is just a GUI for 'Deja-Dup', which is a frontend for 'duplicity', the actual backend making the backups.

Long story short, the answer is no : **the finest time granularity you can achieve is in days, not hours**.

(See https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191)

If you can afford to get rid of the GUI and get back to cron to schedule duplicity backups, you will be able to choose the time of the backup.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies a lot of problems I was having finding information about this app.